# For which value of r does the following equality hold: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}180/3^{4k}$

Tags: calculus

> For which value of r does the following equality hold: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}180/3^{4k}$$

I'm just not making any progress with this. I know from memorization that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n = 1/(1-r)$, but that's about it. I guess that means $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}180/3^{4k}$ is also?

Comment: Woah, major error. Edited.

Comment: tag - (multivariable calculus) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The closed form of a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) is

$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a r^n = \frac{a}{1 - r}$$

Alternatively,

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a r^n = \frac{a}{1 - r} - a = \frac{ra}{1-r}$$

So the right hand side is simply given by

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{180}{3^{4k}} &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{180}{(3^4)^k}  \\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty 180 \left(\frac{1}{3^4}\right)^k
\end{align}

So put this into a closed form, put the left side into a closed form, and solve for $r$.

Comment: Okay, to put into closed form. From $\sum_{n=0}^{inf}ar^n = a/(1-r)$, couldn't we say that $a = 180 and r = (1/3^4)$? Which would give us: $180/(1- (1/3^4))$

Comment: @Ozera The right-hand series starts at $1$, not $0$, ,so the second formula is applicable.

Comment: Ah I see. With $a=180$, $r=1/(3^4)$ we get $(180 * (1/3^4))/(1 - (1/3^4))$ which simplified gets us $9/4$. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know that,

$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a r^n = \frac{a}{1 - r}$$

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{180}{3^{4k}}=180\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{4k}}$$

The $R.H.S$ is a $G.P$ with $$a=\frac{1}{3^{4}}$$ and $$r=\frac{1}{3^{4}}$$ which can be evaluated to be  equal to

$$\frac{\frac{1}{3^{4}}}{1-\frac{1}{3^{4}}}=\frac{1}{80}$$.

Hence the R.H.S evaluates to $$180*\frac{1}{80}=\frac{9}4$$

Which should be equal to $$L.H.S=\frac{1}{1-r}$$ as evaluated by you.

Hence the answer  $$r = \frac{5}9$$.